# How to consume from a local socket in flink that has "/*"after port number where * is the rest of the source?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am new to apache-flink and I need to process some data coming from akka local scoket that's streaming to 'ws://localhost:9000/ws'

In flink API, I only can find a function called 'socketTextStream'
that takes a hostname, port and delimiter

ex:

```
DataStream<String> text = env.socketTextStream(hostname, port, "\n");
```

How can I specify the socket as 'ws://localhost:9000/ws' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `socketTextStream` internally uses regular sockets i.e. `java.net.Socket` for connection with the specified address. But assuming from the address in Your description, You are dealing with WebSockets. You can't use regular sockets to read data from WebSockets. Currently, Flink does not have an API to create datastream from WebSockets AFAIK. The only thing to obtain what You want to obtain is to write Your own `SourceFunction` that will internally use `javax.websocket-api` to create connection and read the data from Your server.